# Telnet doesnt Accept enter as newline

Tags: telnet

I'm trying to send http requests through telnet . I'm able to open the connection to server , and even able to write the first line( GET /uri httpversion) . But , when i'm trying to press enter and provide host name header it doesnt give me the new line, rather it sends that to the server and throws bad request error.

tried changing crlf , mode to console and stream , commandline . but i'm unable to get through it.

client is running on windows10.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards, uday.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally pressed the INSERT key, this key tends to cause problems when editing text or using terminals (Makes input before a letter delete the letter, ex: pressing X in the situation:  |http:// = x|ttp://) .  Press it again to disable.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your inputs. But that didnt solve the issue.:(